# Protein inhibitory process

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, pharmacology

I usually find substances that activates proteins, like ApoA-I, but I don't find substances that inhibit it.

So in an experimental design, could I consider the absence of a drug that directly acts on the increase of a protein could be considered an inhibitory process?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please rephrase it and add some relevant background?

Comment: There are many inhibitors of protein function. Inhibitors are more common, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

No, absence of an stimulating substance is not appropriate to consider as inhibition.

To see why, consider a situation where there are two such substances, substance A and substance B, which can both stimulate protein P (many such relations exist).  If you add only substance B, then protein P will be stimulated. Since P is being stimulated in this case, it would thus not be reasonable to describe the protein being inhibited by the lack of substance A.